# Salesforce Docsign API Integration Account credentials

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am working on SalesForce-DocuSign Integration (eSignature Process). I have successfully connected to Docusign demo environment and tested the APIs & functionality is working as expected.

In my code username, password and Integrator key are hardcoded .

```
// Enter your DocuSign credentials:
String UserName = "abc@xxx.com";
String Password = "abc";    
String IntegratorKey = "****************************";
```

Soon,the code will be moved to production org. When end users started using esignature process, same credentials (Username and password. Example above username and password) can be passed to connect to DocuSign API everytime or the user specific credentials should be passed to connect to Docusign APIs? What is the the best approach for this ? Any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create and send envelopes on behalf of other users.  You will use a generic api account user which will authenticate with the API but you can use SOBO to send the envelope on behalf of another docusign sender that is part of the same account.

For Authorization Grant: 
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo

Easier way using the Authentication Header: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html